# Why is it sometimes impossible to derive macroscopic properties of a system starting from a microscopic analysis?

Tags: emergent-properties

I have read Philip [Anderson](http://robotics.cs.tamu.edu/dshell/cs689/papers/anderson72more_is_different.pdf) and Robert [Laughlin](https://www.nobelprize.org/uploads/2018/06/laughlin-lecture.pdf) articles about emergence. They claim that a macroscopic description of some systems are sometimes **impossible** to be derived from a microscopic analysis. Examples given are the fractional quantum Hall effect and superfluidity.

Having studied statistical mechanics, this sounds very, very surprising to say the least! I really wonder what is going on, if the claim is true (I am almost sure it is, both are Physics Nobel Prize winners).

Why is it impossible to describe the macroscopic properties of some systems, by starting with a microscopic analysis? Does it mean statistical mechanics is limited? What about quantum mechanics?

Comment: As you have read Laughlin's article, I am confused what you actually want to know here. Laughlin gives explicit examples of phenomena that are emergent - e.g. the phonon as a collective excitation of a lattice - and explains why the microscopic analysis cannot see them - e.g. the phonon is a property of the lattice, not of any specific particle in it, the very notion of "sound" or "latticle excitation" doesn't exist at this level. What exactly do you think is left to say here?

Comment: @ACuriousMind I can treat phonons with statistical mechanics. From it, I can even get the DOS and what not. All this from a microscopic point of view where I can count phonons individually, leading to macroscopic occupation number in some cases (BEC). It's not because a phonon is physically spread over the entire infinite crystal that I cannot treat it from a microscopic point of view, IMO. The thing is that, apparently, I cannot always predict all macroscopic properties by treating, say phonons, using stat mech.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the point Laughlin is making. What is an example of a macroscopic property where you think he is saying you cannot get it "using stat mech"?

Comment: @ACuriousMind Probably, indeed. I am thinking about the fractional quantum Hall effect and superfluidity.

Comment: It is *in the vast majority of cases* impossible to derive anything macroscopic from QM alone. See the age-old debate about whether chemistry is reducible to QM or not (for example, https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10698-017-9285-4). Not to mention biology, and all other sciences dealing with very complex systems. At this level, reductionism is a conjecture, not a matter of fact.